# OpenCL on Microsoft Visual Studio: templates cannot be declared to have C linkage

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, opencl

I'm currently learning how to code using OpenCL, and decided to run some sample code. I have downloaded the Intel SDK, Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, and the relevant add-ins for it.

When I try to run a program, an issue arises in regards to one of the "additional dependencies" files included in the %iNTELOCLSDKROOT dependency downloaded from Intel. The error I get when I try to build the solution is that templates cannot be declared to have C linkage (C2894). This error is situated entirely in a single file, called xtr1common. I tried changing the filename from host.cpp to host.c, which removes the C2894 error but then brings up new errors regarding syntax, as it is clearly not written in C.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem, and know how it could be resolved? I'm confused because I highly doubt that Intel have errors in their code, and its something else that I'm most likely not noticing. Just in case there may be an error in the code, I have included it below. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
    // xtr1common internal header
#pragma once
#ifndef _XTR1COMMON_
#define _XTR1COMMON_
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <yvals.h>

 #pragma pack(push,_CRT_PACKING)
 #pragma warning(push,_STL_WARNING_LEVEL)
 #pragma warning(disable: _STL_DISABLED_WARNINGS)
 #pragma push_macro("new")
 #undef new

_STD_BEGIN
    // STRUCT _Nil
struct _Nil
    {   // empty struct, for unused argument types
    };

    // TEMPLATE CLASS integral_constant
template<class _Ty,
    _Ty _Val>
    struct integral_constant
    {   // convenient template for integral constant types
    static constexpr _Ty value = _Val;

    using value_type = _Ty;
    using type = integral_constant;

    constexpr operator value_type() const _NOEXCEPT
        {   // return stored value
        return (value);
        }

    constexpr value_type operator()() const _NOEXCEPT
        {   // return stored value
        return (value);
        }
    };

    // ALIAS TEMPLATE bool_constant
template<bool _Val>
    using bool_constant = integral_constant<bool, _Val>;

using true_type = bool_constant<true>;
using false_type = bool_constant<false>;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS enable_if
template<bool _Test,
    class _Ty = void>
    struct enable_if
    {   // type is undefined for assumed !_Test
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct enable_if<true, _Ty>
    {   // type is _Ty for _Test
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<bool _Test,
    class _Ty = void>
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Test, _Ty>::type;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS conditional
template<bool _Test,
    class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    struct conditional
    {   // type is _Ty2 for assumed !_Test
    using type = _Ty2;
    };

template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    struct conditional<true, _Ty1, _Ty2>
    {   // type is _Ty1 for _Test
    using type = _Ty1;
    };

template<bool _Test,
    class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    using conditional_t = typename conditional<_Test, _Ty1, _Ty2>::type;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS is_same
template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    struct is_same
        : false_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty1 and _Ty2 are the same type
    };

template<class _Ty1>
    struct is_same<_Ty1, _Ty1>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty1 and _Ty2 are the same type
    };

template<class _Ty,
    class _Uty>
    constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<_Ty, _Uty>::value;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS remove_const
template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_const
    {   // remove top level const qualifier
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_const<const _Ty>
    {   // remove top level const qualifier
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    using remove_const_t = typename remove_const<_Ty>::type;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS remove_volatile
template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_volatile
    {   // remove top level volatile qualifier
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_volatile<volatile _Ty>
    {   // remove top level volatile qualifier
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    using remove_volatile_t = typename remove_volatile<_Ty>::type;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS remove_cv
template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_cv
    {   // remove top level const and volatile qualifiers
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_cv<const _Ty>
    {   // remove top level const and volatile qualifiers
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_cv<volatile _Ty>
    {   // remove top level const and volatile qualifiers
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_cv<const volatile _Ty>
    {   // remove top level const and volatile qualifiers
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    using remove_cv_t = typename remove_cv<_Ty>::type;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS _Is_integral
template<class _Ty>
    struct _Is_integral
        : false_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<bool>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<char>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<unsigned char>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<signed char>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

 #ifdef _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED
template<>
    struct _Is_integral<wchar_t>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };
 #endif /* _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED */

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<char16_t>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<char32_t>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<unsigned short>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<short>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<unsigned int>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<int>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<unsigned long>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<long>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<unsigned long long>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_integral<long long>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

    // TEMPLATE CLASS is_integral
template<class _Ty>
    struct is_integral
        : _Is_integral<remove_cv_t<_Ty>>::type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is integral
    };

template<class _Ty>
    constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_integral<_Ty>::value;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS _Is_floating_point
template<class _Ty>
    struct _Is_floating_point
        : false_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is floating point
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_floating_point<float>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is floating point
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_floating_point<double>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is floating point
    };

template<>
    struct _Is_floating_point<long double>
        : true_type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is floating point
    };

    // TEMPLATE CLASS is_floating_point
template<class _Ty>
    struct is_floating_point
        : _Is_floating_point<remove_cv_t<_Ty>>::type
    {   // determine whether _Ty is floating point
    };

template<class _Ty>
    constexpr bool is_floating_point_v = is_floating_point<_Ty>::value;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS is_arithmetic
template<class _Ty>
    struct is_arithmetic
        : bool_constant<is_integral<_Ty>::value
            || is_floating_point<_Ty>::value>
    {   // determine whether _Ty is an arithmetic type
    };

template<class _Ty>
    constexpr bool is_arithmetic_v = is_arithmetic<_Ty>::value;

    // TEMPLATE CLASS remove_reference
template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_reference
    {   // remove reference
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_reference<_Ty&>
    {   // remove reference
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    struct remove_reference<_Ty&&>
    {   // remove rvalue reference
    using type = _Ty;
    };

template<class _Ty>
    using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type;

_STD_END
 #pragma pop_macro("new")
 #pragma warning(pop)
 #pragma pack(pop)
#endif /* RC_INVOKED */
#endif /* _XTR1COMMON_ */

/*
 * Copyright (c) by P.J. Plauger. All rights reserved.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V6.50:0009 */
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean these *errors* are situated in a single file, xtr1common. There's 52 of them in total.

Comment: The problem isn't in this code, but somewhere where it is included. Do you by any chance have `extern "C" { #include <something> }`? Templates cannot have C linkage as there are no templates in the C language.

Comment: I get the error messages described above when I try to build simple examples in the intel example page here > https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl-support/code-samples. For example, I've just loaded up the example > Advanced OpenCL Samples for Windows Image from Buffer. As soon as I build it, the same messages come up from before.. templates cannot be declared to have "c" linkage. I've looked through the code and don't see anything like what you've described. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this header file that #includes xtr1common, and has external C within the program. May this be the source of the issue? I have not changed it since downloading from Intel with the SDK.

```
    /* xtgmath.h internal header */

 #if defined(__cplusplus)
#pragma once
#ifndef _XTGMATH
#define _XTGMATH
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <cstdlib>
#include <xtr1common>

 #pragma pack(push,_CRT_PACKING)
 #pragma warning(push,_STL_WARNING_LEVEL)
 #pragma warning(disable: _STL_DISABLED_WARNINGS)
 #pragma push_macro("new")
 #undef new

_STD_BEGIN
template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2>
    using _Common_float_type_t =
        conditional_t<is_same<_Ty1, long double>::value || is_same<_Ty2, long double>::value, long double,
        conditional_t<is_same<_Ty1, float>::value && is_same<_Ty2, float>::value, float,
        double>>;   // find type for two-argument math function
_STD_END

#define _CRTDEFAULT
#define _CRTSPECIAL _ACRTIMP

#define _GENERIC_MATH1R(FUN, RET, CRTTYPE) \
extern "C" _Check_return_ CRTTYPE RET __cdecl FUN(_In_ double); \
template<class _Ty, \
    class = _STD enable_if_t< _STD is_integral<_Ty>::value>> inline \
    RET FUN(_Ty _Left) \
    { \
    return (_CSTD FUN(static_cast<double>(_Left))); \
    }

#define _GENERIC_MATH1(FUN, CRTTYPE) \
    _GENERIC_MATH1R(FUN, double, CRTTYPE)

#define _GENERIC_MATH1X(FUN, ARG2, CRTTYPE) \
extern "C" _Check_return_ CRTTYPE double __cdecl FUN(_In_ double, ARG2); \
template<class _Ty, \
    class = _STD enable_if_t< _STD is_integral<_Ty>::value>> inline \
    double FUN(_Ty _Left, ARG2 _Arg2) \
    { \
    return (_CSTD FUN(static_cast<double>(_Left), _Arg2)); \
    }

#define _GENERIC_MATH2_CALL(FUN, CRTTYPE, CALL_OPT) \
extern "C" _Check_return_ CRTTYPE double CALL_OPT FUN(_In_ double, _In_ double); \
template<class _Ty1, \
    class _Ty2, \
    class = _STD enable_if_t< _STD is_arithmetic<_Ty1>::value && _STD is_arithmetic<_Ty2>::value>> inline \
    _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2> FUN(_Ty1 _Left, _Ty2 _Right) \
    { \
    typedef _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2> type; \
    return (_CSTD FUN(static_cast<type>(_Left), static_cast<type>(_Right))); \
    }

#define _GENERIC_MATH2(FUN, CRTTYPE) \
    _GENERIC_MATH2_CALL(FUN, CRTTYPE, __cdecl)

template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2,
    class = _STD enable_if_t< _STD is_arithmetic<_Ty1>::value && _STD is_arithmetic<_Ty2>::value>> inline
    _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2> pow(const _Ty1 _Left, const _Ty2 _Right)
    {   // bring mixed types to a common type
    typedef _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2> type;
    return (_CSTD pow(static_cast<type>(_Left), static_cast<type>(_Right)));
    }

//_GENERIC_MATH1(abs, _CRTDEFAULT)  // has integer overloads
_GENERIC_MATH1(acos, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(asin, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(atan, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH2(atan2, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(ceil, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(cos, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(cosh, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(exp, _CRTDEFAULT)

_GENERIC_MATH1(fabs, _CRT_JIT_INTRINSIC)

_GENERIC_MATH1(floor, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(fmod, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1X(frexp, _Out_ int *, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1X(ldexp, _In_ int, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(log, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(log10, _CRTDEFAULT)
//_GENERIC_MATH1(modf, _CRTDEFAULT)     // types must match
//_GENERIC_MATH2(pow, _CRTDEFAULT)  // hand crafted
_GENERIC_MATH1(sin, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(sinh, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(sqrt, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(tan, _CRTDEFAULT)
_GENERIC_MATH1(tanh, _CRTDEFAULT)

        // C99 MATH FUNCTIONS

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION fma

inline float _Fma(float _Left, float _Middle, float _Right)
    {   // call float fma
    return (_CSTD fmaf(_Left, _Middle, _Right));
    }

inline double _Fma(double _Left, double _Middle, double _Right)
    {   // call double fma
    return (_CSTD fma(_Left, _Middle, _Right));
    }

inline long double _Fma(long double _Left, long double _Middle,
    long double _Right)
    {   // call long double fma
    return (_CSTD fmal(_Left, _Middle, _Right));
    }

template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2,
    class _Ty3> inline
    _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty2, _Ty3>>
    fma(_Ty1 _Left, _Ty2 _Middle, _Ty3 _Right)
    {   // bring mixed types to a common type
    typedef _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty2, _Ty3>> type;
    return (_Fma((type)_Left, (type)_Middle, (type)_Right));
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION remquo

inline float _Remquo(float _Left, float _Right, int *_Pquo)
    {   // call float remquo
    return (_CSTD remquof(_Left, _Right, _Pquo));
    }

inline double _Remquo(double _Left, double _Right, int *_Pquo)
    {   // call double remquo
    return (_CSTD remquo(_Left, _Right, _Pquo));
    }

inline long double _Remquo(long double _Left, long double _Right, int *_Pquo)
    {   // call long double remquo
    return (_CSTD remquol(_Left, _Right, _Pquo));
    }

template<class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2> inline
    _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2>
    remquo(_Ty1 _Left, _Ty2 _Right, int *_Pquo)
    {   // bring mixed types to a common type
    typedef _STD _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2> type;
    return (_Remquo((type)_Left, (type)_Right, _Pquo));
    }

_GENERIC_MATH1(acosh, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(asinh, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(atanh, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(cbrt, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(copysign, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(erf, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(erfc, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(expm1, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(exp2, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(fdim, _CRTSPECIAL)
//_GENERIC_MATH3(fma, _CRTSPECIAL)  // hand crafted
_GENERIC_MATH2(fmax, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(fmin, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(hypot, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1R(ilogb, int, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(lgamma, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1R(llrint, long long, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1R(llround, long long, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(log1p, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(log2, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(logb, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1R(lrint, long, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1R(lround, long, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(nearbyint, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(nextafter, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1X(nexttoward, _In_ long double, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH2(remainder, _CRTSPECIAL)
//_GENERIC_MATH2X(remquo, _CRTSPECIAL)  // hand crafted
_GENERIC_MATH1(rint, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(round, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1X(scalbln, _In_ long, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1X(scalbn, _In_ int, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(tgamma, _CRTSPECIAL)
_GENERIC_MATH1(trunc, _CRTSPECIAL)

#undef _CRTDEFAULT
#undef _CRTSPECIAL
#undef _GENERIC_MATH1R
#undef _GENERIC_MATH1
#undef _GENERIC_MATH1X
#undef _GENERIC_MATH2_CALL
#undef _GENERIC_MATH2

 #pragma pop_macro("new")
 #pragma warning(pop)
 #pragma pack(pop)
#endif /* RC_INVOKED */
#endif /* _XTGMATH */
 #endif /* defined(__cplusplus) */

/*
 * Copyright (c) by P.J. Plauger. All rights reserved.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V6.50:0009 */
```